# Issues while uploading an object on S3 bucket

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to run AWS SDK (boto3) code on my machine. I want to upload some files on S3 bucket. However I read those files from a disk and for that I need to run the code with `sudo -E`. When I run the code like that, I get 
`ERROR:root:An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied` error. 
But when I run the same code without `sudo` (and after commenting disk related operations that needs sudo), it works perfectly fine. 
Has anyone else faced this issue? 
Can anyone help me fix this?

Reference Code - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/python-s3-put_object.py.html

Comment: How did you defined the AWS access & secret key? did you use environment variable or `~/.aws/credentials` file?

Comment: What happens when you run `aws sts get-caller-identity`? How about `sudo sh -c 'aws sts get-caller-identity'`? When you run a sudo command, it switches your user to `root` and changes your `$PATH` and other env vars accordingly. What's likely happening is `aws` is configured for the regular user, but not for the root user.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40127702/my-aws-cli-didnt-work-with-sudo

Answer (score 0):

The aws credentials need to be given read permission for your current user, so that boto client is able to read them

$ chown -R user:user .aws/