# AWS Lightsail push-container-image, getting NoCredentialProviders error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I am getting an error running `aws lightsail push-container-image` command, I have set `AWS_PROFILE` command set and then verify that everything is working with `aws configure list`
When I run,

```
 sudo aws lightsail push-container-image --region us-east-1 --service-name <my service> \
 --label <my label> --image <my docker image> --debug
```

I get the following error,

```
-----------------------------------------------------
NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
    For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
2021-03-22 13:35:04,368 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Exception caught in main()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "awscli/clidriver.py", line 457, in main
  File "awscli/clidriver.py", line 586, in __call__
  File "awscli/customizations/commands.py", line 191, in __call__
  File "awscli/customizations/lightsail/push_container_image.py", line 65, in _run_main
  File "subprocess.py", line 516, in run
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['lightsailctl', '--plugin', '--input-stdin']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Command '['lightsailctl', '--plugin', '--input-stdin']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I am using `lightsailctl` version 1.0.0 and `AWS CLI` version `aws-cli/2.1.31 Python/3.8.8 Linux/5.8.0-44-generic exe/x86_64.ubuntu.20 prompt/off` and `Docker version 20.10.5, build 55c4c88`

Comment: Why are you using `sudo`? This is failing because it's looking at root's aws configs rather than your users.

Comment: Also, depending on your sudo config, `AWS_PROFILE` is probably not being inherited by the child process, which is a common default for sudo for security reasons.

Comment: If I don't use user then I get permission denied errors from Docker.

Comment: Can you otherwise not use `docker` as your user? Have you tried adding your user to the `docker` group and then relogging?

Comment: @jordanm - I refered to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40127702/my-aws-cli-didnt-work-with-sudo question and was able to resolve the issue.

Comment: Out of all your options, that's probably the worse one.